# How to connect two shapes to create a mesh in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have this hexagonal shape

[image]

The red line in the middle has length 10.
Now I draw the same hexagon, with a length of 20. I'll place this new hexagon far from the first one in the z axis, and I want to connect their edges so that I have a trapezoidal shape with a hexagonal cross section.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See the code example here for how to create your own custom `BufferGeometry`: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

Comment: Another option: extrude that hexagonal shape, then shift specific vertices with math.